# JIRA - Confirmation message on state transitions

Tags: workflow, jira

Is it somehow possible to force JIRA to display a confirmation message on state transitions? In our case we want to show somehow a notification or a reminder to the developer when he sets an issue from *open* to *resolved* to remember to review the entries in the field acceptance criteria.

Comment: you can try to map a window to a workflow transition, check that link https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/mapping-a-screen-to-a-workflow-transition-720634253.html

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Checkbox that is like called like "Confirm" that has the description with the confirmation message. Then make a new screen that is a "confirmation screen" that has the checkbox on it.

Then for the transition that you require, add this to the be the screen for the transition then make the checkbox mandatory using something like the groovy script runner.

You would also want to add a post condition that reset the checkbox after its all done so it could be re-used if you wanted to use this screen multiple times within the same workflow.